# Hide Respondent's Email Address in Google Form

Tags: google-forms

When someone responds to my Google Form, it displays their email address at the top of the form.

[image]

I've disabled the option `Disable autosave for all respondents` in the form settings but the message still appears in the live form.

Is there a way to turn off this information from displaying in the Google Form?

Answer (score 0):

No, that message cannot be removed. However, it can be changed.

When `Disable autosave for all respondents` is set to active, that message will show "(Shared)"

When the setting is disabled, that message shows "(Not Shared)".

You cannot remove the message, as it is there to inform user if their email is auto-collected or not.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid having the user email shown is to someway make that the user sign out of their Google account session or to open the form in incognito mode.